# websites painfully slow sometimes

Tags: linux

i have a 1and1 account dedicated linux machine never had a problem with it.
httpd and mysqld seem to be running just fine.
ping and trace are also fine..

one domain on the machine is www.hundig.com

any ideas where i could look why it is so slow or not loading at all?
when i reboot it seems faster. just rebooting httpd doesnt change anything.

(tried doing a local curl and it doesnt load. a curl on google works fine. must be local)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the site in Firefox with enabled Firebug. It'll show you, on which file it hangs. For each file it shows dns resolve time and download time.
2. Watch `top` output and look for excessive load, memory consumption, etc.
3. Enable harder logging of php (E_WARNING at least) and look into php error log
4. Enable slow log in MySQL and look for slow SQL queries.

About bad local curl - try to `wget http://www.hundig.com`. If the server has problem with dns resolve of the domain, and php script is trying to download something from this url, that could be the slowing down place. But it doesn't explain "faster after reboot"

Regards,

Martin

Comment: i figured out it must have something to do with apache... not sure yet what though

Comment: seems like it hangs but it doesnt use more memory than usual

Comment: I'd add strace to the suggestions made by mkudlacek. Try to strace your httpd processes when the site is slow.